# Assembly signing key expired

Tags: c#, assembly-signing

I created a key using the sn tool to sign the assemblies in my project.
I noticed that the key expired 4 months ago, but visual studio doesnt complain about this, and still signs the dlls.
Will there be any impact on my customers when they install these assemblies? (If it matters some of the assemblies go to the GAC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Strong Name keys don't expire](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx#S4).

You may be thinking of [Code Signing certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx), which do.

Comment: the pfx file that I select from the signing tab in the project properties has expired

Comment: pfx is a Code Signing certificate, but the sn tool only creates Strong Name keys. So there is some confusion going on.

Comment: I'm using the assembly sign tab in the project settings and select the pfx key, which is strog name key then, and it shouldnt expire? I installed this pfx to cert store and saw that it expired

Comment: Again, NO. The pfx is not the strong name key. Those are two different concepts, as I describe above. Pfx is a code signing certificate and is used to sign certain types of code (the top half of the signing page "sign the ClickOnce manifests"). The strong name key is for the bottom half of that page ("sign the assembly"). They have different uses and are not interchangeable.

Comment: For the bottom half -- the UI Reads "Choose a strong name key file" and from that drop down box you can choose a pfx file -- according to the Visual Studio UI, a .pfx file is a "strong name key".  A pfx file can also expire.

Comment: Regardless of the terminology you use, if I have an expired pfx file, and I select it below in the "sign the assembly; choose a strong name key file" area, why does it work?  And what are the impacts of doing this?

Comment: (Additionally, according to the first link you posted, a .pfx file is a type of strong name key file.)